# Modifying the built-in colors of matplotlib

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib

I would like to modify the default colors of matplotlib without creating a new custom color_cycle or palette. My main reason is that I want to replot graphs I already made without having to chase all the strings 'b','r', ... to get more modern colors like metal blue and so on.

I found that the RGB code of these built-in colors seem to be defined in `matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors` but modifying this dictionary doesn't help me. Creating a new color_cycle doesn't help me with the graphs in my old ipython notebook.

Any idea before I start thinking hacking matplotlib's sources?

Thanks,
JC

Comment: Why not just use a custom `color_cycle`? (You can define it either per-axes or in your matplotlib rc.) Changing `'cyan'` to mean "pink" seems like a very weird way to go about this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lot of reasons, I think this is a bad idea...

However, if you really want to do it, just modify `matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.colors` instead of `matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors`.

`colorConverter` is a singleton (well, by convention only) instance of `ColorConverter` that matplotlib uses behind-the-scenes to convert color specifications to rgb.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Evil!!
colors.colorConverter.colors['b'] = (0.1, 1.0, 0.2)
# You may need to clear the cache that ColorConverter keeps if 'b'
# has alreadly been used...
colors.colorConverter.cache = {}

plt.plot(range(10), color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Be aware that modifying `colorConverter.colors` will only change what the single-letter color abbreviations do!  Using `"blue"` will still give you blue.

If you really want to mess with people, you'll need to monkey-patch `colorConverter.to_rgb` instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

# Evil!!
colors.colorConverter.to_rgb = lambda x: tuple(np.random.random(3))

plt.plot(range(10), color='pink')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. It looks definitely what I wanted. I must ask tho why it is a so bad idea as long as I stay reasonable (meaning not changing 'k' or modifying plain blue to a variation of blue).

Comment: @jchristophe - If you're just doing it for your own codebase, it's not bad at all.  It's more if anyone else comes along and looks at the code in isolation.  They'll be confused as to why `"r"` isn't producing the usual bright red, etc.  As with anything else, used reasonably and in a limited scope, it's not a bad idea at all. It's just an easy avenue for unexpected behavior (a.k.a. "abuse").  By "I think this is a bad idea", I mostly meant "I think it would be better to explicitly specify colors" (rather than changing what the abbreviations mean).